# MvxLinearLayout inside an ItemTemplate of ExpandableListView

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to add a MvxLinearLayout inside of ExpandableListView's ItemTemplate but I'm getting this error:

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: 
bindingContext is null during MvxAdapter creation - Adapter's should only be created
when a specific binding context has been placed on the stack
```

How can I make it work?
Do I have to make my ExpandableListView class inherit from another Mvx Interface?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Stuart I am facing same issue, and my code is as per below, Can you please suggest me what m i doing wrong here ?                                 listView = FindViewById<MvxExpandableListView> (Resource.Id.toclist);
listView.Adapter  = new TicketExpandableListAdaptor (this);                  public class TicketExpandableListAdaptor : MvxExpandableListAdapter
 {
  public Context context;
  public TicketExpandableListAdaptor(Context context): base(context)
  {
   this.context = context; 
  }